# Join showing null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    ORD_CODE,
    ORL_EVENT,
    ACT_ACT
FROM
    R5ORDERS inner join R5ORDERLINES on ORD_CODE = ORL_ORDER
    inner join R5ACTIVITIES on ACT_ORDER = ORL_ORDER
WHERE
    ORL_EVENT = '144933'
GROUP BY 
    ORD_CODE, ORL_EVENT, ACT_ACT
ORDER BY 
    ACT_ACT
```

It displays the correct data, but ACT_ACT does not show some values (like 10) because ORD_CODE is null in that case.

This is what I get:

```
ORD_CODE     ORL_EVENT    ACT_ACT
22057         144933        20
22145         144933        30
22146         144933        40
22147         144933        50
```

I tried with LEFT or RIGHT join, but nothing changes. I would like to have this:

```
ORD_CODE     ORL_EVENT    ACT_ACT
NULL          144933        10
22057         144933        20
22145         144933        30
22146         144933        40
22147         144933        50
```

Sample data:

R5ORDERS table

```
ORD_CODE   
22057   
22145     
22146      
22147
```

R5ORDERLINES table

```
ORL_ORDER     ORL_EVENT    ORL_PRICE      ORL_ORDQTY
22057         10            1000              2
22145         10              50             10
22146         10              25             5
22147         10              20             1
```

R5ACTIVITIES table

```
ACT_ORDER     ACT_ACT
NULL           10
22057          20
22145          30
22146          40
22147          50
```

Here is the sample data in a consumable format so that others can work with it.

```
declare @Orders table
(
    ORD_CODE int
)
insert @Orders values
(22057)
, (22145)
, (22146)
, (22147)

declare @OrderLine table
(
    ORL_ORDER int
    , ORL_EVENT int
    , ORL_PRICE int
    , ORL_ORDQTY int
)

insert @OrderLine values
(22057, 10, 1000,  2)
,(22145, 10,   50, 10)
,(22146, 10,   25, 5)
,(22147, 10,   20, 1) 

declare @Activities table
(
    ACT_ORDER int
    , ACT_ACT int
)

insert @Activities values
(NULL , 10)
, (22057, 20)
, (22145, 30)
, (22146, 40)
, (22147, 50)
```

Comment: Edit the question with some sample data.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used?

Comment: Because there's one I initially edited for more clarity.... Just added it with some sample date.

Comment: You should use some aliases and include them on every column. It is impossible for anybody to know what table each column belongs to.

Comment: How do you expect to get ACT_ACT of 10 to display when the join won't match that row to an Order?

Comment: @SeanLange Well, that's the thing. I want to get all ACT_ACT, even if it doesnt match an order. It seems like a left join would solve it, but it doesn't.
Btw, for aliases, the first 3 characters indicate the table they come from ORD, ORL, ACT.

Comment: Not really clear what you want. I have to say that prefixes like that are one of my pet peeves. When column names changes across tables it is so hard to work with. But for the question at hand you posted some sample data but it doesn't match now with your sample query or the desired output. What would you expect as output from your sample data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need `left join` at all instead :

```
select r1.ACT_ORDER as ORD_CODE, r2.ORL_EVENT, r3.ACT_ACT
from R5ACTIVITIES r1 left join
     R5ORDERLINES r2
     on r2.ORL_ORDER = r1.ACT_ORDER left join
     R5ORDERS r3
     on r3.ORD_CODE = r2.ORL_ORDER;
```

Comment: If I do that (selecting from R5ACTIVITIES), I can see ACT_ACT 10, but it returns a lot of repeated rows. I get the ACT_ACT repeated for every ORD_CODE.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this:

```
FROM R5ACTIVITIES LEFT join R5ORDERLINES on  ACT_ORDER = ORL_ORDER
                  RIGHT join   R5ORDERS on ORD_CODE = ORL_ORDER
```

Comment: plus you can not use inner join if you want to retrieve NULL values

Comment: already tried with left and right joins, and nothing changes. That's why im still using inner join until I find the real solution...

Answer (score 0):

You are using an inner join on R5ORDERS and R5ORDERLINES. A null value will not show because an inner join by definition selects records that have matching values in both tables. To get all ACT_ACT values to show, select from R5ACTIVITIES and join your other tables to it using a left join.